# FileInputFormat where filename is KEY and text contents are VALUE

Tags: file, input, dictionary, format, hadoop

I'd like to use an entire file as a single record for `MAP` processing, with the filename as the key.
I've read the following post: [How to get Filename/File Contents as key/value input for MAP when running a Hadoop MapReduce Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716138/how-to-get-filename-file-contents-as-key-value-input-for-map-when-running-a-hadoo)
 and while the theory of the top answer is solid, no code or "how-to" is actually provided.

Here is my custom `FileInputFormat` and the corresponding `RecordReader`, which compile, yet do not produce ANY record data.
Thanks for any help.

```
public class CommentsInput
    extends FileInputFormat<Text,Text> {
protected boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path filename)
{
    return false;
}
@Override
public RecordReader<Text, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext ctx)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return new CommentFileRecordReader((FileSplit) split, ctx.getConfiguration());
}
```

/////////////////////////

```
public class CommentFileRecordReader
    extends RecordReader<Text,Text> {
private InputStream in;
private long start;
private long length;
private long position;
private Text key;
private Text value;
private boolean processed;
private FileSplit fileSplit;
private Configuration conf;

public CommentFileRecordReader(FileSplit fileSplit, Configuration conf) throws IOException
{
    this.fileSplit = fileSplit;
    this.conf=conf;
}

/** Boilerplate initialization code for file input streams. */
@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit split,
                     TaskAttemptContext context)
                        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();

    fileSplit = (FileSplit) split;
    this.start = fileSplit.getStart();
    this.length = fileSplit.getLength();
    this.position = 0;
    this.processed = false;

    Path path = fileSplit.getPath();
    FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
    FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(path);

    CompressionCodecFactory codecs = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);
    CompressionCodec codec = codecs.getCodec(path);
    if (codec != null)
        this.in = codec.createInputStream(in);
    else
        this.in = in;

    // If using Writables:
    // key = new Text();
    // value = new Text();
}
public boolean next(Text key, Text value) throws IOException
{
    if(!processed)
    {
        key = new Text(fileSplit.getPath().toString());
        Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
        FSDataInputStream in = null;
        byte[] contents = new byte[(int) fileSplit.getLength()];
        try
        {
            in = fs.open(file);
            IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
            value.set(contents.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }
        processed = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
    // TODO parse the next key value, update position and return true.
    return false;
}

@Override
public Text getCurrentKey() {
    return key;
}

@Override
public Text getCurrentValue() {
    return value;
}

/** Returns our progress within the split, as a float between 0 and 1. */
@Override
public float getProgress() {
    if (length == 0)
        return 0.0f;
    return Math.min(1.0f, position / (float)length);
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (in != null)
        in.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you get the correct solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a way to define your own key class and make sure your classes use it. You can look up how to define your own key class and you can get a file name by calling hte `getName()` method on its path then use it to make your key.